# How to set up vim's identation for literate Haskell programming?

Tags: haskell, vim, indentation, auto-indent, literate-programming

When I turn on `autoindent` for a regular *.hs file, the after pressing *Enter* the new line is indented as expected. However, this doesn't work with [literate Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/literate.html) *.lhs files whose code lines start with `>` (AKA "bird-tracks"). The cursor is always positioned at the first column.

How can I set up vim so that when I'm inside a piece of code in a *.lhs file (and let\s say have `autoindent` on), pressing *Enter* creates a bird track at the new line and indents appropriately?

**Update:** To give an example, let's say  have

```
> myfn x | x <= 0     = 0
>        | x == 1     = 1▌
```

where `▌` represents the position of the cursor (I hope you have no problem seeing the unicode character.) If I press *Enter*, I end up with

```
> myfn x | x <= 0     = 0
>        | x == 1     = 1
▌
```

whereas I want

```
> myfn x | x <= 0     = 0
>        | x == 1     = 1
>        ▌
```

Comment: Please show what you have and what you want for those of us not literate enough to know what a bird track is.

Comment: @romainl Updated, with an example.

Comment: Today I learned a new programming word.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should be easy to achieve with

```
:set formatoptions+=ro
```

or `:se fo+=ro` for short.

With `r` and `o` in [`'formatoptions'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27formatoptions%27), Vim attempts to insert the comment "leader" including indentation on new lines inside a comment (that is, a non-comment in literate Haskell).

To make this setting automatically, set up an autocommand in your vimrc.

```
autocmd FileType lhaskell setlocal formatoptions+=ro
```

Tip: Use [`CTRL-U`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#i_CTRL-U) to remove the auto-inserted leader when you don't need it.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. Apparently, the code blocks starting with `> ` aren't treated as comments, so `ro` doesn't apply to them (I already have those flags on, I have `tcroql`).

Comment: @PetrPudlák Oh, it does work! Check if the `lhaskell` filetype is correctly recognized `:set ft?`.

Comment: @PetrPudlák I imagine you have a plugin that interferes with things. Anyway, you can try `:set comments+=:>` to make the `>` a comment leader.

Comment: You're right, I tried it on another machine and it works. So I'll have to go through the plugins and find out which one is causing the trouble.

Comment: It was caused by _haskellmode_ plugin. After uninstalling it, it works.